# What is the difference between depth and height in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, nodes, terminology

This is a simple question from algorithms theory.
The difference between them is that in one case you count number of nodes and in other number of edges on the shortest path between root and concrete node.
Which is which?

Comment: Tip: to avoid confusion between terminologies: 1. Height: Imagine measuring a person's height, we do it from toe to head (leaf to root). 2. Depth: Imagine measuring depth of a sea, we do it from earth's surface to ocean bed (root to leaf).

Comment: To add on to @Yesh excellent analogy: for some inner node in the middle of the tree, it's depth is how many levels it is beneath the root node, and it's height is how levels it is above its bottom-most child node.

Comment: be careful here guys - height is measured head to toe, just like it's defined from node to leaf, and would be traversed down in a tree.  Just think of a stick figure that lost a leg. The node there doesn't define his height, because it's not the longest path. We can though, say we found the depth of that node

Answer (score 963, accepted):

I learned that depth and height are properties of a *node*:

- The **depth** of a node is the number of edges from the node to the tree's root node.
  A root node will have a depth of 0.
- The **height** of a node is the number of edges on the *longest path* from the node to a leaf.
  A leaf node will have a height of 0.

Properties of a *tree*:

- The **height** of a tree would be the height of its root node,
  or equivalently, the depth of its deepest node.
- The **diameter** (or **width**) of a tree is the number of *nodes* on the longest path between any two leaf nodes. The tree below has a diameter of 6 nodes.

[image: A tree, with height and depth of each node]

Comment: +1 was about to add quote with same content from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29

Comment: hmm I thought the terminology is not ambiguous, however thanks for the link.

Comment: is that means height == max depth

Comment: @rkm_Hodor: Yes, the _height_ of a tree is always equal to the _depth_ of the deepest node.

Comment: Very well explained regarding height and depth in Binary trees.

Comment: "Note that depth doesn't make sense for a tree" - Why isn't the depth useful?

Comment: Could you please cite a source for your claim that diameter of a tree counts nodes instead of edges?  This conflicts with the usual definition of the diameter of a graph (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) which asks for the longest path.

Comment: @j_random_hacker It's a matter of definition, pick the one most useful to you. To get from the number of vertices to the number of edges, just subtract 1. I prefer to count the number of vertices, as this results in a graph with only one node having width 1, and an empty graph having width 0. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html

Comment: I am confused some website says count nodes, here it says count edges.
in this link, it talks about finding maximum depth, in the example it gives, the depth of the tree is 3, but if I count edges it will be 2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-find-the-maximum-depth-or-height-of-a-tree/

Comment: On a different note, `depth == number_of_level` of a binary tree.

Comment: In https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/, the depth of the root is 1 instead of 0, pls explain it for me?

Answer (score 62):

height and depth of a tree is equal...

but height and depth of a node is not equal because...

the height is calculated by traversing from the given node to the deepest possible leaf.

depth is calculated from traversal from root to the given node.....

Comment: "height is calculated by traversing from leaf to the given node" it is not correct , the leaf must be the one which is deepest among all the leaves of the given node.

Answer (score 19):

According to Cormen et al. Introduction to Algorithms (Appendix B.5.3), the depth of a node X in a tree T is defined as the length of the simple path (number of edges) from the root node of T to X.  The height of a node Y is the number of edges on the **longest** downward simple path from Y to a leaf.  The height of a tree is defined as the height of its root node.

Note that a simple path is a path without repeat vertices.

The height of a *tree* is equal to the max depth of a *tree*.  The depth of a node and the height of a node are not necessarily equal.  See Figure B.6 of the 3rd Edition of Cormen et al. for an illustration of these concepts.

I have sometimes seen problems asking one to count nodes (vertices) instead of edges, so ask for clarification if you're not sure you should count nodes or edges during an exam or a job interview.

Comment: Is there is any differnce in counting the nodes and edges. Seems to be both will give the same result. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @jdhao how can the depth of root be 2? It's either 0 (if edges are considered) or 1 (if nodes are considered).

Comment: @neowulf33, yes, I am terribly wrong. The depth of the root node should be 0. I will delete my comment in order not to confuse people.

Answer (score 12):

I know it's weird but Leetcode defines depth in terms of number of nodes in the path too. So in such case depth should start from 1 (always count the root) and not 0. In case anybody has the same confusion like me.

Comment: Is that so? See https://leetcode.com/problems/diameter-of-binary-tree/ which defines it in terms of edges.

Comment: @OtienoRowland that problem does not mention "depth". This other problem clearly does: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/

Answer (score 6):

Simple Answer:

Depth:
     
1. **Tree**: **Number of edges/arc** from the root node to the leaf node of the tree is called as the Depth of the Tree.
    
2. **Node**: **Number of edges/arc** from the root node to that node is called as the Depth of that node.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to understand those concept is as follow:
Depth: Draw a horizontal line at the root position and treat this line as ground. So the depth of the root is 0, and all its children are grow downward so each level of nodes has the current depth + 1.

Height: Same horizontal line but this time the ground position is external nodes, which is the leaf of tree and count upward.

Comment: Nice way to remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to make this post because I'm an undergrad CS student and more and more we use OpenDSA and other open source textbooks. It seems like from the top rated answer that the way height and depth is being taught has changed from one generation to the next, and I'm posting this so everyone is aware that this discrepancy now exists and hopefully won't cause bugs in any programs! Thanks.

From the [OpenDSA Data Structures & Algos book](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/CS3/html/BinaryTree.html#definitions-and-properties):

> If n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>,...,n<sub>k</sub> is a sequence of nodes in the tree such
>   that n<sub>i</sub> is the parent of n<sub>i</sub>+1 for 1<=i<k, then this sequence
>   is called a path from n<sub>1</sub> to n<sub>k</sub>. The length of the path is k−1.
>   If there is a path from node R to node M, then R is an ancestor of
>   M, and M is a descendant of R. Thus, all nodes in the tree are
>   descendants of the root of the tree, while the root is the ancestor of
>   all nodes. **The depth of a node M in the tree is the length of the
>   path from the root of the tree to M. The height of a tree is one more
>   than the depth of the deepest node in the tree.** All nodes of depth d
>   are at level d in the tree. The root is the only node at level 0, and
>   its depth is 0.
>
> [image: Figure 7.2.1]
>
> Figure 7.2.1: A binary tree. Node A is the root. Nodes B and C are
>   A's children. Nodes B and D together form a subtree. Node B has
>   two children: Its left child is the empty tree and its right child is
>   D. Nodes A, C, and E are ancestors of G. Nodes D, E, and F
>   make up level 2 of the tree; node A is at level 0. The edges from A
>   to C to E to G form a path of length 3. Nodes D, G, H, and I
>   are leaves. Nodes A, B, C, E, and F are internal nodes. The depth
>   of I is 3. The height of this tree is 4.

Comment: For what it's worth, the definition at this link has been changed to: **"The depth of a node M in the tree is the length of the path from the root of the tree to M. The height of a tree is the depth of the deepest node in the tree."**

Comment: @ashtree: Did you mean to say that the height of this tree is 3, and not 4?

Comment: @TaimurAhmedQureshi Looks like since I posted, they changed the definition, which ^kaya3 noted. So originally the height would have been 4, but with kaya3's answer, now, yes it's 3.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Daniel A.A. Pelsmaeker and Yesh analogy is excellent. I would like to add a bit more from hackerrank tutorial. Hope it helps a bit too.

- The depth(or level) of a node is its distance(i.e. no of edges) from tree's root node.
- The height is number of edges between root node and furthest leaf.
- **height(node) = 1 + max(height(node.leftSubtree),height(node.rightSubtree))**.
  Keep in mind the following points before reading the example ahead.
- Any node has a height of 1.
- Height of empty subtree is -1.
- Height of single element tree or leaf node is 0.
  [image: Example to calculate height of tree]

Answer (score 3):

1. Depth:

---

The **depth** of a node in the tree is the **length of the path from the root to the node.** The depth of the tree is the maximum depth among all the nodes in the tree.

[image: HEIGHT AND DEPTH OF THE TREE]

2. Height:

---

The **height** of the node is the **length of the path from that node to the deepest node in the tree.** The height of the tree is the length of the path from the root node to the deepest node in the tree. (Eg: the height of the tree in the above example is four (count the edges, not the nodes)).
A tree with only one node has zero height.

For more reference about basics of trees, visit: [INTRODUCTION AND PROPERTIES OF TREES](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/guided-paths/data-structures-algorithms/content/118521/offering/1380974)

Answer (score 2):

**Depth**: how many edges are there above the node that is depth of a node 
**Height**: how many edges are there below the node that is height of a node

````
 Node1 // depth = 0 and height = 2 => root node
  |
 / \
Node2 Node3 //depth = 1 and height = 1
|     |
Node4 Node5  //depth = 2 and height = 0  => leaf node```
````

Answer (score 2):

**The depth** of a node is the number of edges present in path from the root node of a tree to that node.

---

**The height** of a node is the number of edges present in the longest path connecting that node to a leaf node.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The “depth” (or equivalently the “level number”) of a node is the number of edges on the “path” from the root node

The “height” of a node is the number of edges on the longest path from the node to a leaf node.

Comment: Hi Diva. As the question already has an accepted answer and this particular answer do not add any additional details. You may find some related discussion about the SO policy [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243243/vote-to-delete-answers-as-duplicates-of-earlier-answers/243271#243271)

Answer (score -1):

The overall depth of the tree is equal to the height of the tree and the same for the level of the tree but if for a particular node height is not equal to the depth because the definition of **Depth** states that the longest path from the root node to that node, In case of **Height** it is from that node to the leaf node.

overall tree, D=H=L
but for a node D=L But D may not be equal to H.

Comment: Other answers say the same thing in clearer manner.