# What is the difference between the height of a tree and depth of a tree?

Tags: tree

I don't mean height or depth of node. My initial knowledge is that they are the same. Am I correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between tree depth and height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height)

Answer (score 2):

Copied [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603707/146622):

> [image]
>
> The depth of a node is the number of edges from the node to the tree's
>   root node. A root node will have a depth of 0. The height of a node is
>   the number of edges on the longest path from the node to a leaf. A
>   leaf node will have a height of 0

Comment: How about the depth of TREE and height of TREE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height

Comment: These answers explain the height and depth of a single node in a tree. I want to know the height and depth of the entire tree.

Comment: The **height** of a tree is equal to the **max depth** of a tree - the longest path from the root to a leaf

Comment: Other way to put it, **Height** defines how many nodes are in a direct line between the deepest node in the tree and the current node, where **depth** defines how many parent nodes the current node has.