# Number of nodes of a tree where each node has two children nodes

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have a tree that has the following form:

[image]

On the first pictures, the height of the tree is 1 and there are 3 total nodes. 2 for 7 on the next and 3 for 15 for the last one. How can I determine how many number of nodes a tree of this form of `l` height will have? Also, what kind of tree is that (is it called something in particular?)?

Comment: is it a Full Binary Tree?

Comment: it's both a full and a complete binary tree ... which makes it a perfect binary tree (see wikipedia link in my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [perfect binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)

You can get the number of node considering this recursive approch:

```
n(0) = 1
n(l+1) = n(l) + 2^l
```

so

```
n(l) = 2^(l+1) - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A complete binary tree at depth ‘d’ is the strictly binary tree, where all the leaves are at level d.

- for fig1, d=1
- for fig2, d=2
- for fig3, d=3

So, Suppose a binary tree T of depth `d`. Then at most 

## `2(d+1)-1`

 nodes `n` can be there in T.

- for fig1, d=1; `2(1+1)-1`=`2(2)-1`=`4-1`=3
- for fig2, d=2; `2(2+1)-1`=`2(3)-1`=`8-1`=7
- for fig3 d=3; `2(3+1)-1`=`2(4)-1`=`16-1`=15

The *height*(`h`) and *depth*(`d`) *of a tree* (the length of the longest path from the root to leaf node) are numerically equal.

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603707/2534513) detailing how to compute depth and height.

Comment: note: down vote was a result of posting wrong equation (mixed up html tags for superscript). Errors have been rectified.

Answer (score 1):

The number of nodes in a complete tree is...

n = 2^(h+1) - 1.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like "a perfect binary tree".
"a binary tree is a tree data structure in which each node has at most two children"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree
A perfect tree is "A binary tree with all leaf nodes at the same depth."
http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/perfectBinaryTree.html

height to maximum number of nodes in perfect binary tree
=2^(height+1)-1

number of nodes to minimum height
=CEILING(LOG(nodes+1,2)-1,1)

Definitions associated with Binary trees can be found at the Wikipedia wiki cited earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be understood like this.

In case of a **perfect binary tree** 
total number of leaf nodes are **2^H** (H = Height of the tree)

and total number of internal nodes are **2^H - 1**

Hence the total number of nodes will be **2^H + 2^H - 1** which is **2^(H+1) - 1** as mentioned by others.

Hope this will help.