# Binary tree depth

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

Trying to find depth of binary search tree. Have done something with a bit of google search but my code is crashing:

```
int treeDepth(int depth) const
        {
            int l = this->left->treeDepth(depth);
            int d = this->right->treeDepth(depth);

            return depth + std::max(l, d);
        }
```

calling this function with: `root->treeDepth(1);`

Comment: And if `left` or `right` is null?

Comment: didn't add that yet but in this case i know it isn't

Comment: So how does the tree end ....

Comment: Is the tree circular, with all the leaves redirecting back to the root of the tree?

Comment: Oh ok I see what do you mean now

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, I think that you may be confusing the *depth* of a tree with the *height* of a tree. Refer to [What is the difference between tree depth and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height) for an explanation.

For example, following are the depth and height of the nodes in this (binary) tree ('0' being the root):

```
    0     -- depth 0, height 2
   / \
  1   2   -- depth 1, height 1 and 2, respectively, for nodes 1 and 2
 / \
3   4     -- depth 2, height 0
```

As you can see, that the depth of the tree root is '0', which is O(1) computation. The height of the tree, however, is more interesting with regards to recursion and can be computed using the following:

```
struct TreeNode {
    T _value;
    typedef TreeNode* node_ptr;    
    node_ptr _left, _right;
};
...
int treeHeight(Node* node)
{
    return std::max(node->_left? 1 + height(node->_left) : 0,
                    node->_right? 1 + height(node->_right) : 0);
}
...
std::cout << treeHeight(root);
...
```

The fundamental idea is this:
During the recursive (depth-first) traversal, if a leaf node is reached, return a value of '0' (which is the height of every leaf node). Otherwise, compute the height of the tree rooted at the non-leaf node (which is the max of the heights of the left subtree and the right subtree of that node + 1 for the node itself). Start from the *root* of the tree.

The **second** aspect that I want to address in your question is regarding what I gather from your function signature:

```
int treeDepth(int depth) const
```

and the way you are calling it:

```
root->treeDepth(1);
```

The depth of a tree is **not** conducive to being a property of the *root*. Instead, it is a property of the tree, which is composed of tree nodes, one of which is the *root* node. So, I would define the class (C++ struct shown here) as follows:

```
template<class T>
struct BinaryTree {
    struct TreeNode {
        T _value;
        typedef TreeNode* node_ptr;    
        node_ptr _left, _right;
    };
    TreeNode _root_node;
    typedef typename TreeNode::node_ptr node_ptr;
    node_ptr _root;
    ...
    int height(node_ptr node) const;
    ...
};
```

**Finally**, finding the *depth* of a *given node* in a tree:

```
int depth(node_ptr node) const;
// returns depth of node if it is in the tree, else -1
```

is a problem where you may apply recursion. However, a recursive approach is not natural and a breadth-first (or level-order) traversal will be more suited for this.

Comment: The root node depth can be either 0 or 1, depends on you refer to the number of edges or nodes along a path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up a little bit about recursion.

One of the fundamental tenets of recursion is that there must be a "stop condition" which will at some point terminate the recursion.

Otherwise, you have what is known as "runaway recursion", your stack fills up, and your program crashes and burns.

In your case, a "stop condition" would be reaching a `this->left` or `this->right` which happens to be NULL.

So, for the future readers (as suggested by Barmar in a comment)

```
int l = left == NULL? 0 : left->treeDepth(depth);
int d = right == NULL? 0 : right->treeDepth(depth);
```

Comment: You should show how to incorporate this check into his code.

Comment: @Barmar No, I shouldn't.  If he can't do that, he does not deserve to receive a passing grade in his assignment.

Comment: What about all the future readers? This is supposed to be a general-purpose resource.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe next week, after his assignment is due.  If the question is still here.  Otherwise, I'd be rep wh_oring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was able to make it.

Answer (score 0):

there are actually many problems in your code.

Fist of all you need to implement a recursion termination, that is a condition needed to stop your function from calling its self forever
in your case you need to write something like 
`if(left==nullptr && rigth==nullptr)
    return depth;`

The recursion termination is VERY IMPORTANT! you always need it when you're writing a recursive function. Without you're 100% going into a never ending loop (in the best case).

then, when you re-call your function you need to change the depth value
i mean, if you're going down on another node of the tree it means that the tree is tall at least "depth+1" so you need to pass depth + 1 not just depth,
and at the and of the function just write

```
return std::max(l,d);
```

also,you're using pointers, always write a condition to check if you're really trying to access a well defined address, that is, before even trying to access an address (ex. this->left) you need to write a condition like `if( this->left!=nullptr)` (`nullptr` from c++ 11 otherwise `NULL` will as well get the work done)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
int treeDepth() const
        {
            int l = left == NULL? 0 : left->treeDepth();
            int d = right== NULL? 0 : right->treeDepth();
            return 1 + std::max(l, d);
        }
```

In this case you don't need additional paramether "depth"