# Finding longest root to leaf path in a tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, code-reuse, longest-path

I need to find the longest ROOT to LEAF path in a tree.
I already have code to find the shortest root to leaf and I was wondering if I could reuse it in any way to find the longest path.

```
// Recursive function used by leftMostShortest
// to print the first shortest root to leaf path
void AlberoCircuito::printPath(string Data, unordered_map<string,
                             string> parent)
{
    // If the root's data is same as
    // its parent data then return
    if (parent[Data] == Data)
        return;

    // Recur for the function printPath
    printPath(parent[Data], parent);

    // Print the parent node's data
    pathMinimo.push_back(parent[Data]);
}


// Function to perform level order traversal
// until we find the first leaf node
vector<string> AlberoCircuito::leftMostShortest(NodoAlbero* root)
{
    // Queue to store the nodes
    queue<NodoAlbero*> q;

    // Push the root node
    q.push(root);

    // Initialize the value of first
    // leaf node to occur as -1
    string LeafData = " ";

    // To store the current node
    NodoAlbero* temp = NULL;

    // Map to store the parent node's data
    unordered_map<string, string> parent;

    // Parent of root data is set as it's
    // own value
    parent[root->value] = root->value;

    // We store first node of the smallest level
    while (!q.empty()) {
        temp = q.front();
        q.pop();

        // If the first leaf node has been found
        // set the flag variable as 1
        if (!temp->leftPtr && !temp->rightPtr) {
            LeafData = temp->value;
            break;
        }
        else {

            // If current node has left
            // child, push in the queue
            if (temp->leftPtr) {
                q.push(temp->leftPtr);

                // Set temp's left node's parent as temp
                parent[temp->leftPtr->value] = temp->value;
            }

            // If current node has right
            // child, push in the queue
            if (temp->rightPtr) {
                q.push(temp->rightPtr);

                // Set temp's right node's parent
                // as temp
                parent[temp->rightPtr->value] = temp->value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Recursive function to print the first
    // shortest root to leaf path
    printPath(LeafData, parent);

    // Print the leaf node of the first
    // shortest path
    pathMinimo.push_back(LeafData);
    return pathMinimo;
}
```

So this is the code I'm using to find the shortest path and store it in a vector. These are members of a class.

Is there any way to just modify it and reuse it? Or do you think I have to start over? Thanks :)

Comment: If you really want to reuse the code can't you just not break when you find a leave but continue to process nodes? You know that the last node proceed would me one of those with the longest path. I would, however do a simple recursive function in which the longest-path of a current node would be 1 + the longest path between the left node and the right node.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean in the second part of the comment because I'm terrible at coding, but wouldn't that just give me the height of the tree?

Comment: Isn't that what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height