# Should the max depth of a binary tree exclude the root?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

So far, I saw 2 different implementations for a max depth of a tree here,

1. **1st one, `max depth === level - 1`:**
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-find-the-maximum-depth-or-height-of-a-tree/

   - Which means, for the base case, `if !node: return -1`
   - So a three level tree has a max depth of 2
2. **2nd one, `max depth === level`:**
   https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/

   - Which means, for the base case, `if !node: return 0`
   - So a three level tree has a max depth of 3

**The implementation in javascript is just as simple as this:**

```
function maxDepth(node){
   if (!node) return -1;
   return Math.max(maxDepth(node.left),maxDepth(node.right))+1;
}
```

Which one is correct? What am I missing here?

Also, max depth of a tree is equal to the height of a tree, right? Although it calculates in a different way, depth is from node to root, height is from node to leaf node.

Comment: Matter of opinion.

Comment: [Is your question answered?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The terms take different meaning at different places. So, it should be clarified wherever used.

---

For root, level = 1, depth = 0 and height = 1.

level = depth + 1.

Source: http://typeocaml.com/2014/11/26/height-depth-and-level-of-a-tree/

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology):

> The height of a node is the length of the longest downward path to a
> leaf from that node. The height of the root is the height of the tree.
> The depth of a node is the length of the path to its root (i.e., its
> root path). This is commonly needed in the manipulation of the various
> self-balancing trees, AVL Trees in particular. The root node has depth
> zero, leaf nodes have height zero, and a tree with only a single node
> (hence both a root and leaf) has depth and height zero.
> Conventionally, an empty tree (tree with no nodes, if such are
> allowed) has height −1

---

Another interesting discussion on [What is the difference between tree depth and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that means leetcode is wrong?

Comment: Can't say wrong because they have specified their usage of the terms.